# Csharp Not able to read excel using oledb

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I was trying to read an Excel file from an .aspx page using Visual Studio localhost. I kept the Excel in the root folder, but when trying to read it, it shows the following exception:

> The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to
>   the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you
>   need permission to view and write its data.

My oledb code

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xlsx"].ConnectionString;
OleDbConnection oledbConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
try
{
    // Open connection
    oledbConn.Open();

    // Create OleDbCommand object and select data from worksheet Sheet1
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", oledbConn);

    // Create new OleDbDataAdapter
    OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();

    oleda.SelectCommand = cmd;

    // Create a DataSet which will hold the data extracted from the worksheet.
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    // Fill the DataSet from the data extracted from the worksheet.
    oleda.Fill(ds, "Employees");

    // Bind the data to the GridView
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    // Close connection
    oledbConn.Close();
}
```

connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="xls" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=ExcelToParse.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"/>
    <add name="xlsx" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=ExcelToParse.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Can somebody point what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Smells like a user permission issue.  Can you try running as an admin user?  Also, if memory serves, the OLEDB stuff might run in a different process/user space... which would obviate my first notion haha ... but those two areas are where I'd look

Comment: Why don't you use the mighty NPOI library? It works even when you don't have installed excel on your machine...

Answer (score 1):

First run this command in command prompt to kill all open Excel processes.

```
taskkill /f /im excel.exe
```

You need to dispose the connection object. Then change your code in your finally block to-

```
finally
{
    // Close connection
    oledbConn.Close();
    oledbConn.Dispose();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oledbConn);
}
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Also check what @Malachi suggested in the comments above.